# Hosting Flask(Python) app throws CGI error

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I have followed all the steps as per the azure website. I can see the python 3.6 version running on Azure. I have installed the python 3.6 extension and added a proper web.config file. When I try to open my URL I am getting the below error

http://myuniqueappname114.azurewebsites.net/

[image]

Any idea how to fix this error pls

Comment: Is there any useful error information in the wfastcgi.log file (default location is D:\home\LogFiles)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, the issue was caused by your `web.config` file configured incorrectly to not start up your flask app from IIS.

Here is my case for deploying flask `Hello World` app on Azure Website, which you can refer to to check your deployment whether be correct.

1. I installed a Python extension `python364x86` under `D:\home`. Maybe yours installed is `python364x64`.
2. I commanded `pip install flask` in the path `D:\home\python364x86` via Kudo console.
3. My file structure under `wwwroot` as the figure below via command `tree /F /A`.
   [image]
4. The `__init__.py` file content is like the Flask offical `Hello` demo.

   ```
   from flask import Flask
   app = Flask(__name__)

   @app.route("/")
   def hello():
       return "Hello World!"

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       app.run()
   ```
5. My `web.config` file content is as below, note `python364x86` I used in the property `scriptProcessor` of tag `system.webServer > handles > add` at here.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     <appSettings>
       <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="D:\home\site\wwwroot" />
       <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="myflask.app" />
     </appSettings>
     <system.webServer>
       <handlers>
           <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\home\python364x86\python.exe|D:\home\python364x86\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
       </handlers>
     </system.webServer>
   </configuration>
   ```

Then the demo app works.
[image]

If your case is different from mine, please post your `web.config` file content and other necessary info to help fixing up your issue.

Comment: Thanks it worked. it is because of the web.config only. Thank you