# Setting up a Python server in Azure Web Apps

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

I'm looking for an understandable way of configuring a Flask application to run on Azure Web Apps. I'd like to be able to have the environment as close to the original one as possible, although I understand using a ready-made service brings some requirements.

What I appreciate about my local setup is:

- An easy way to run a server with Waitress just by running a `.py` script
- Having my files as an importable "development" package, providing a situation with no path manipulations but an arbitrary location in the file system (`pip install -e ./`)

It is very easy to set up an application and start it with Flask. This is my most simple `app.py`.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return 'Hi.'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run('0.0.0.0', 5000)
```

Now there's this [guide](https://github.com/ilkarman/CV_end_to_end/blob/master/02-WebApp/AzureWebApp.md) on how to get a Python website up in Azure. I think it has loads of unnecessary steps, downloading wheels to from a separate server, modifying `os.path` to import libraries and using a `virtualenv`. Don't get me wrong: `virtualenv` is useful but I'm just trying strip the process down to its bare minimum. Additionally, for me at least the `virtualenv` activation script does not work.

Another [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/publish-to-app-service-windows?view=vs-2019), this time by Microsoft themselves says that Windows developers should move to Azure Web App for Linux instead. But for the time being, I'm stuck with a Windows app. They provide some configuration assistance.

A Python installation was provided. It is strangely located in `D:\home` and its interpreter cannot be started using a simple `python` command. Installing libraries works though: `python -m pip install lib`. A configuration file should be constructed from some Visual Studio template which at least my Visual studio can't find. So what I have now filling in with the first guide is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="PythonHandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule"
        scriptProcessor="D:\home\Python364x64\python.exe|D:\home\Python364x64\wfastcgi.py"
        resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"/>
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Another line should be added somewhere based on the doc. Although, it is unclear where exactly.

```
<add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="FlaskAzurePublishExample.app"/>
```

So what I'd like to know is:

- What are the minimum steps required to get this minimal application running?
- Can I run a server of my own at all? How about several using different ports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question, you can refer to my answer for the other existing SO thread [Hosting Flask(Python) app throws CGI error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54121080/hosting-flaskpython-app-throws-cgi-error/54142861#54142861) to run the minimal Flask application. And there is an issue in your code, which be started up by `wfastcgi.py` using `app.run()`, not to use `app.run('<ip or host for listening>', '<a port you want>')`. On Azure, IIS as HTTP server for Python to run a flask app via FastCGI.

So for your second question, you can run your own server behind IIS reverse proxy, but the only port on Azure Web Site is `80` on IIS for serving Python Web App via FastCGI.